# What is wrong with my attempt to resize an image by half?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take an image, divide it's size by half, and eventually save its results to another file.

```
from PIL import Image

image0 = Image.open("cwu_logo0.jpg")

image0Width = print(image0.width)
image0Height = print(image0.height)
image0.resize(image0Width/2, image0Height/2)
```

I do not understand the error message that prints out when it runs, this is what it is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `image0Width` and `image0Height` to the result of `print()`. `print` has a return type of `None`.

The `print()` method writes to the console output. What you want to do is assign the variable without calling the print method on the same line as the assignment of the height/width variables.

```
image0Width = image0.width
image0Height = image0.height

print(image0Width)
print(image0Height)

image0.resize(image0Width/2, image0Height/2)
```

Comment: It still does not work, when I run that code it presents with an error that says: ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (77.0). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)